# AngularJS directive compile after loading dynamic content with $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, compilation

I want to dynamically load content into an angular app.

Content will be created from html templates and data getting through php loaded async with the $.get function from jQuery.

```
var app = angular.module('contentApp', []);
app.directive("contentListContainer", function($compile) {  
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element) {

            //def
            var templateData1;
            var databaseData;

            //get
            var getTemp1 = $.get("/lib/templateData1.html", function(data, status) {
                templateData1 = data;
            });

            var getData = $.get("/lib/getData.php?type=all", function(data, status) {
                databaseData = JSON.parse(data);
            });

            //build
            $.when(getTemp1, getData).then(function() {
                var uiData = "";

                //combine templates using database Data and build HTML DOM string

                //uiData string example: "<div><div>{{var1}}</div><div>{{var2}}</div></div>"
                $element.html(uiData);
                $compile($element.contents())($scope); 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The final DOM string contains some {{}} expressions i want to control with an angular controller.

```
app.controller('contentCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.var1 = 5;
    $scope.var2 = 10;
});
```

Problem: The expressions won't be compiled and used by the angular controller, they are only shown as plain text.

Comment: Instead of using `$.get`, it would be better to use [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get). AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. The `$.get` method is not integrated with the AngularJS framework execution context and its digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$.get` and `$compile`, simply use the `templateUrl` property in the directive:

```
app.directive("contentListContainer", function($compile) {  
    return {
        templateUrl: "lib/templateData1.html",
        link: function($scope, $element) {
        }
    }
})
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/jsFvMRZenKCBSIQdcUSv?p=preview)

For more information, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - templateUrl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-templateurl-)

---

### Update

> But i need to modify the template before showing it on the screen, because the template will be dynamically changed (on load) based on the database Data.

Instead of using `$.get`, it is better to use [$http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#get). The `$.get` method is not integrated with the AngularJS framework execution context and its digest cycle.

```
app.directive("contentListContainer", function($compile,$http) {  
    return {
        //templateUrl: "lib/templateData1.html",
        link: function($scope, $element) {
            var uiData = "";
            $http.get("lib/templateData1.html")
            .then(function(response) {
                uiData = response.data;
                //uiData string example: "<div><div>{{var1}}</div><div>{{var2}}</div></div>"
                $element.html(uiData);
                $compile($element.contents())($scope);
            });
        }
    };
})
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

The `$compile` works correctly with `$http.get`.

The [DEMO #2 on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/tOC3ie3v0QFtZdHLKSa6?p=preview)

Comment: But i need to modify the template before showing it on the screen, because the template will be dynamically changed (on load) based on the database Data.